# Watermark behaves erratically, possibly due to bad event time (client clock skew)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have a flow of events, roughly 1k-3k/s and mostly heartbeats, coming from video streaming clients, which we aggregate into sessions. We use a Session window with a 10 minute gap duration and default triggering (i.e. no early triggers and no lateness allowed).

What we observe is (1) erratic and bursty emission of sessions, and (2) an erratic and "jumpy" watermark, at times going as far back in history as 2 weeks.

We believe this can be associated with a subset of clients having local clock skew, affecting event time.

This would mean that instead of marking events from "bad" clients as late, the watermark adjusts itself according to these new (old) timestamps, effectively stalling the emission of recently ended sessions. And only when no bad events have been observed for some predefined time, the watermark is advanced to realtime and recent sessions can be emitted.

Is this a reasonable hypothesis? 
Is this the expected behavior with the conditions described above?
Given our assumption is correct, what would the recommended solution be?

Answer (score 0):

Your hypothesis does sound reasonable.  The Pub/Sub watermark tracking will ignore occasional data from far in the past, but if this happens commonly enough it will behave as you describe.  One possible solution is to use the timestamp of when the record was received in Cloud Pub/Sub instead of the timestamp based on the local skewed clock.  You can do this by just omitting the .timestampLabel() call on your read transform.

Comment: After further investigation we see that less than 0.4% of the events arrive with event times more than 10 minutes behind arrival time. Perhaps it is the pattern (whole sessions being skewed) that tricks the watermark heuristic.

Comment: Is there a way to control (the sensitivity of) how watermark is calculated? Also, to ignore event time and go for arrival time, would mean dropping a major feature of the Beam model, as out-of-order arrivals will pass unnoticed and introduce correctness errors.

Comment: There's not currently a way to control the watermark estimate.  I'm not quite proposing switching to arrival time; you can use the pubsub publish time.  This means you still get the same guarantees if your pipeline is slow or has an outage.